# Decode JSON file from api SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, fetch, swiftui, decode

I'm trying to decode some JSON data from a URL and display it in a list. I've tried different ways but no one works(some times it returns me unknown error or simply not displaying data)
This should be the struct to represent the JSON format

```
import SwiftUI

struct Country : Decodable {
    var thailand : [Case]
}

struct Case : Decodable  {
    var date : String
    var confirmed : Int
    var deaths : Int
    var recovered : Int
}
```

A little part of the JSON(but it's all the same):

```
{
  "Thailand": [
    {
      "date": "2020-1-22",
      "confirmed": 2,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-23",
      "confirmed": 3,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-24",
      "confirmed": 5,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-25",
      "confirmed": 7,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-26",
      "confirmed": 8,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 2
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-27",
      "confirmed": 8,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 2
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-28",
      "confirmed": 14,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 5
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-29",
      "confirmed": 14,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 5
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-30",
      "confirmed": 14,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 5
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-31",
      "confirmed": 19,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 5
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-1",
      "confirmed": 19,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 5
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-2",
      "confirmed": 19,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 5
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-3",
      "confirmed": 19,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 5
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-4",
      "confirmed": 25,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 5
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-5",
      "confirmed": 25,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 5
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-6",
      "confirmed": 25,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 5
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-7",
      "confirmed": 25,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 5
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-8",
      "confirmed": 32,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 10
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-9",
      "confirmed": 32,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 10
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-10",
      "confirmed": 32,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 10
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-11",
      "confirmed": 33,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 10
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-12",
      "confirmed": 33,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 10
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-13",
      "confirmed": 33,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 12
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-14",
      "confirmed": 33,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 12
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-15",
      "confirmed": 33,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 12
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-16",
      "confirmed": 34,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 14
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-17",
      "confirmed": 35,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 15
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-18",
      "confirmed": 35,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 15
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-19",
      "confirmed": 35,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 15
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-20",
      "confirmed": 35,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 15
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-21",
      "confirmed": 35,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 17
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-22",
      "confirmed": 35,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 17
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-23",
      "confirmed": 35,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 21
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-24",
      "confirmed": 35,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 21
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-25",
      "confirmed": 37,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 22
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-26",
      "confirmed": 40,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 22
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-27",
      "confirmed": 40,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 22
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-28",
      "confirmed": 41,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 28
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-29",
      "confirmed": 42,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 28
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-1",
      "confirmed": 42,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 28
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-2",
      "confirmed": 43,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 31
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-3",
      "confirmed": 43,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 31
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-4",
      "confirmed": 43,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 31
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-5",
      "confirmed": 47,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 31
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-6",
      "confirmed": 48,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 31
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-7",
      "confirmed": 50,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 31
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-8",
      "confirmed": 50,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 31
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-9",
      "confirmed": 50,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 31
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-10",
      "confirmed": 53,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 33
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-11",
      "confirmed": 59,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 34
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-12",
      "confirmed": 70,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 34
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-13",
      "confirmed": 75,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 35
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-14",
      "confirmed": 82,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 35
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-15",
      "confirmed": 114,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 35
    }
  ],
  "Japan": [
    {
      "date": "2020-1-22",
      "confirmed": 2,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-23",
      "confirmed": 1,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-24",
      "confirmed": 2,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-25",
      "confirmed": 2,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-26",
      "confirmed": 4,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-27",
      "confirmed": 4,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-28",
      "confirmed": 7,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-29",
      "confirmed": 7,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-30",
      "confirmed": 11,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-31",
      "confirmed": 15,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-1",
      "confirmed": 20,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-2",
      "confirmed": 20,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-3",
      "confirmed": 20,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-4",
      "confirmed": 22,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-5",
      "confirmed": 22,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-6",
      "confirmed": 45,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-7",
      "confirmed": 25,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-8",
      "confirmed": 25,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-9",
      "confirmed": 26,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-10",
      "confirmed": 26,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 4
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-11",
      "confirmed": 26,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 9
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-12",
      "confirmed": 28,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 9
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-13",
      "confirmed": 28,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 9
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-14",
      "confirmed": 29,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 9
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-15",
      "confirmed": 43,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 12
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-16",
      "confirmed": 59,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 12
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-17",
      "confirmed": 66,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 12
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-18",
      "confirmed": 74,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 13
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-19",
      "confirmed": 84,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 18
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-20",
      "confirmed": 94,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 18
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-21",
      "confirmed": 105,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 22
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-22",
      "confirmed": 122,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 22
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-23",
      "confirmed": 147,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 22
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-24",
      "confirmed": 159,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 22
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-25",
      "confirmed": 170,
      "deaths": 1,
      "recovered": 22
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-26",
      "confirmed": 189,
      "deaths": 2,
      "recovered": 22
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-27",
      "confirmed": 214,
      "deaths": 4,
      "recovered": 22
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-28",
      "confirmed": 228,
      "deaths": 4,
      "recovered": 22
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-2-29",
      "confirmed": 241,
      "deaths": 5,
      "recovered": 32
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-1",
      "confirmed": 256,
      "deaths": 6,
      "recovered": 32
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-2",
      "confirmed": 274,
      "deaths": 6,
      "recovered": 32
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-3",
      "confirmed": 293,
      "deaths": 6,
      "recovered": 43
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-4",
      "confirmed": 331,
      "deaths": 6,
      "recovered": 43
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-5",
      "confirmed": 360,
      "deaths": 6,
      "recovered": 43
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-6",
      "confirmed": 420,
      "deaths": 6,
      "recovered": 46
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-7",
      "confirmed": 461,
      "deaths": 6,
      "recovered": 76
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-8",
      "confirmed": 502,
      "deaths": 6,
      "recovered": 76
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-9",
      "confirmed": 511,
      "deaths": 10,
      "recovered": 76
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-10",
      "confirmed": 581,
      "deaths": 10,
      "recovered": 101
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-11",
      "confirmed": 639,
      "deaths": 15,
      "recovered": 118
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-12",
      "confirmed": 639,
      "deaths": 16,
      "recovered": 118
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-13",
      "confirmed": 701,
      "deaths": 19,
      "recovered": 118
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-14",
      "confirmed": 773,
      "deaths": 22,
      "recovered": 118
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-3-15",
      "confirmed": 839,
      "deaths": 22,
      "recovered": 118
    }
  ]}
```

Here I try to decode the JSON and insert it in a dynamic list

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var cases = [Case]()

    var body: some View {
        List(cases , id: \.date) { i in
            VStack{
                Text(i.date)
                Text("\(i.deaths)")
                Text("\(i.confirmed)")
                Text("\(i.recovered)")

            }.onAppear(perform: self.loadData)

    }

}
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Country.self, from: data) {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print(decodedResponse)
                        self.cases = decodedResponse.thailand
                    }
                    return
                }
            }

            // if we're still here it means there was a problem
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")

        }.resume()

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid the `try?`, use a `do`/`catch`! You are ignoring error if there is one. For instance `Thailand` vs `thailand` (uppercase for the first letter).

Comment: For multiple countries delete `Country` and decode `[String:[Case]]`

Comment: I’ve tried but still doesn’t work. It gives me no error but it displays an empty list.

Comment: *It gives me no error*. No surprise, you are ignoring all possible errors.

Comment: any reference to some solutions ? I'm pretty new to swift so I'm still learning

Answer (score 0):

for decode your response you can use this way:

```swift
typealias Country = [String: [Case]]


struct Case : Decodable  {
    var date : String
    var confirmed : Int
    var deaths : Int
    var recovered : Int
}
```

then decode your data

```swift
decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Country.self, from: data)
```

`decodedResponse` gives you a Dictinaory that includes all of the countries.

for loop in countries, you can set for and achieve info for a one country

```swift
for country in decodedResponse.keys {
     let cases = decodedResponse[country]
}
```

Comment: Where should I put the keys of the country ? Thanks so much

Comment: `decodedResponse.keys` contains country names. you can search in it for a target you need

Comment: I don't get it. I'm sorry

Comment: If I understand correctly if you need cases for a certain country, for example, Japan, you can do this way: `let countryName = "Japan"
                        if decodedResponse.keys.contains(countryName) {
                            self.cases = decodedResponse[countryName] ?? []
                        }`